# IsInRole not working due to name of "role"

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.Net Core web api. I have a claim where the user has the role "Admin." If I explicitly check for it with the string value of "roles", I get the correct value:

I am not able to use these, however:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Admin")]
```

or

```
var isAdmin = this.User.IsInRole("Admin");
```

If I use this:

```
    var roles = this.User.Identities.SelectMany(i =>
    {
        return i.Claims
            .Where(c => c.Type == "roles")
            .Select(c => c.Value)
            .ToList();
    });
```

then is shows up:

```
roles.FirstOrDefault()
"Admin"
```

I am guessing that the default is using "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" instead of "roles" for ClaimType.

I do have this in my startup.cs, which I would expect to address this:

```
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options => 
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
        });
```

But no joy.

Thanks!
~john

Comment: This is still failing for me. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Please let us know where you are getting the roles from? AAD or You are databases

Answer (score 0):

That line alone won't work. From the sample [Support in ASP.NET Core middleware libraries](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles#support-in-aspnet-core-middleware-libraries) , another flag needs to be set as well.

> // This is required to be instantiated before the OpenIdConnectOptions
> // starts getting configured.
> // By default, the claims mapping will map claim names in the old format to >
> // accommodate older SAML applications.
> // 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role' instead
> //  of 'roles'
> // This flag ensures that the ClaimsIdentity claims collection will be built from the claims in the token
>
> ```
>         JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
> ```